# FOR and MOVE in same statement in a BATCH file

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, scripting, directory

I am trying to move multiple .ARC files from sub-directories within a primary directory to one of the other sub-directories. I can get this FOR statement to run just fine if I manually type it in the command line, but running it from script doesn't seem to be working at all (with the variables assigned).

Can anyone see that I am doing something wrong? It's under my impression that I have all the correct syntax in place for this to work without any issues.

```
:main
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    cls
    echo.
    set /P acct=Please type the 9 digit account number you would like to restore: 
    set acctDir=x:\!acct!
    set acctDir2=media1\Setup\setup.exe /cd
    set log=c:\log.txt


    echo. Starting on !date! !time! on !Computername! >> !log!
    echo.
    echo The account number you selected is: !acct!
    echo.

    goto :user

:user

    set /p answer=Is this correct (Y/N)? 
    echo.

    if /i !answer!==y goto :yes (
    ) else ( 
        echo.
        echo Ok. Let's try again^^!
        echo.
        pause
        cls
        goto :main
        )
    )

:yes

    set c=0
    For /f %%a in ('dir !acctDir! /B /A:D') do (
    set /a c+=1
    echo !c!    %%a
    set dir!c!=%%a
    )

    echo. 
    set /p userIn="Select a directory [1-!c!]: "
    set userDir=!dir%userIn%!

    echo.
    echo You selected !userDir! for your data retrieval.
    echo.
    goto :string

:execute

    echo.
    echo The Data Protector Program will now be initialized...
    start !acctdir!\!userDir!\!acctDir2!

    goto :string


:string

    set sumLog=!acctdir!\!userDir!\SummaryLog.txt
    set succ=finished

    findstr " .*!succ!" !sumLog!
    if exist errorlevel 0 (
        pause
        goto :move
    ) else (
        goto :eof
    )

:move
    set acctDir3=media1
    set x=x:\!acct!\!userDir!
    set y=x:\!acct!\!userDir!\!acctdir3!

    echo !x!
    pause
    echo !y!
    pause
    for /r "!x!" %%i in (*.ARC) do move "%%i" "!y!"
    pause

    :: for /r "X:\101004357\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM" %%g in (*.ARC) do move "%%g" "X:\101004357\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM\Media1"



endlocal
goto :eof
```

Please disregard the Access Denied as I will correct that issue on my own. However, the output I get if I manually run the same FOR statement from the command line is:

```
X:\>for /r "X:\101004357\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM" %g in (*.ARC) do move "%g" "X:\101004357\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM\Media1"

X:\>move "X:\101004357\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM\Media1\FILES1.ARC"     
"X:\101004357\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM\Media1"
Access is denied.
0 file(s) moved.

X:\>move "X:\101004357\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM\Media2\FILES2.ARC"  
"X:\101004357\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM\Media1"
Access is denied.
0 file(s) moved.

X:\>move "X:\101004357\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM\Media3\FILES3.ARC"  
"X:\101004357\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM\Media1"
Access is denied.
0 file(s) moved.
```

If I run it from the script, I get no output except to go to `:eof`. Please see the output from the script:

```
Please type the 9 digit account number you would like to restore: 101004357

The account number you selected is: 101004357

Is this correct (Y/N)? y

1    Jan_14_2014_12_49_11_900PM
2    Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM

Select a directory [1-2]: 2

You selected Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM for your data retrieval.

[2014-01-23 12:15:14 InfoTrace (8209)]DVD Media image creation finished at: Thu Jan 23 12:14:50 2014

Press any key to continue . . .
x:\101004357\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM
Press any key to continue . . .
x:\101004357\Jan_20_2014_6_56_55_953PM\media1
Press any key to continue . . .
Press any key to continue . . .
```

If you notice between the double `PAUSE` syntax above is where the `FOR` statement should have ran. But it never does and moves to the second pause without any output or any kind of move, etc.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
for /r "!x!" %%i in (*.ARC) do move "%%i" "!y!"
```

to

```
for /r "%x%" %%i in (*.ARC) do move "%%i" "%y%"
```

`!var!` is not evaluated until **after** the `for` loop is running. Only use `!var!` on a variable that has changed **within** a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`.

I'd also advise to not use a <kbd>:</kbd> in `goto` except for the special case of `goto :eof`

and

```
if exist errorlevel 0 (
```

means "if the file named 'errorlevel`exists, execute the excutable named`0`

No idea what you are trying to do here, but `IF ERRORLEVEL n` is TRUE if `errorlevel` is n **or greater than n**. `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` is therefore always true. `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1` is a test for errorlevel=0. So is `IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0`, except that the former can be used within a block but the latter cannot.

Comment: This worked by changing the `!var!` to `%var%` in the FOR statement. I  was taught that if you `set local enabledelayedexpansion` that you need `!var!` in explanation points?  Can you emphasize on the `error` part for me so I can understand? I'm trying to say that if the error returns that the string exists, then `goto` sub-routine `:move` IF it does not exist then go to `:eof`

Comment: After a `findstr` the magic variable `errorlevel` will have a numeric value. 0 means "found"; other means "not found". You need to use `if errorlevel 1 (thingtodofornotfound) else (thingtodoforfound)` because the `if errorlevel n` test for `n=0` will always be true (the test is actually for `errorlevel **>**=n`, not `errorlevel==n`) `If exist name` is a test for whether the file `name` exists. `If defined name` is a test for whether the ordinary environment variable `name` exists.